# Getting random numbers when calling function whith argument beginning with zeros

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, function-call

I have items in list with 8-digits and most of them begin with two zeros. When I want to call function and pass it's unique number, almost always when it starts with "00" it gets some seemingly random numbers. I still don't know how or why it is happening.
Here is the example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agapetos/EbpbX/).

HTML:

```
<div id="working">
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00119001)" value="00119001" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00113008)" value="00113008" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(68745696)" value="68745696" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(11112222)" value="11112222" /><br/>
</div>
<div id="notworking">
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00113004)" value="00113004" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00113003)" value="00113003" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00106002)" value="00106002" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="sample(00120003)" value="00120003" /><br/>
</div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

JS:

```
function sample(a) {
  var b = "0000000"+a;
  b = b.substr(b.length-8);
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="Input: "+a+" | Output: "+b;
}
```

To clarify the problem:
I expect to get the same number in a function that was used in argument to call it, but for some reason, some times I get totally different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in thinking these numbers are the IDs / reference numbers of something-or-other? If so, then it's more appropriate to store them as strings instead of numbers:

```
<input type="button" onclick="sample('00119001')" value="00119001" /><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`00113004` is interpreted as octal. This doesn't happen when you have a 8 or a 9 in your literal because the js engine guesses that it can't be octal.

To make a decimal literal, remove the `0` at the start

```
<input type="button" onclick="sample(113004)" value="00113004" /><br/>
```

If you really want to have 0, use a string :

```
 <input type="button" onclick="sample('00113004')" value="00113004" /><br/>

function sample(a) {
  var b = "0000000"+Number(a);
  b = b.substr(b.length-8);
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML="Input: "+a+" | Output: "+b;
}
```

Comment: What about the 4th case that is working - there are only 1's and 2's (11112222). Is it because it is 8-digit combination of characters where first one is not zero?

Comment: A number literal not starting with a 0 is interpreted as decimal. That's the "normal" interpretation : you never start a number literal with a 0 unless you want it to be interpreted as octal.